How to make popup work correctly on photo gallery
I made a popup for each individual image on my photo gallery, but it won't pop up when I click on it. When I try and click on the image, it registers the click, but doesn't actually make the popup appear.
I've tried re-arranging the button element and messing with the JS code. Overall, I think the issue may be on the CSS side of things.
Here is the relevant code snippet:


function togglePopup() {
  document.getElementById("popup-1").classList.toggle("active");
}
.photo-gallery {
 width: 90%;
 margin: auto;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
 grid-gap: 20px;
  }

.pic {
 margin-top: 130px;
position: relative;
height: 230px;
border-radius: 10px;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px lightgray;
cursor: pointer;
}

.pic img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 border-radius: 10px;
 }

 .website::before {
 content: "This website!";
 text-align: center;
 }

 .popup .overlay {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
 z-index: 1;
 }

 .popup {
 display: none;
 }


.popup .content {
 position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
background: #fff;
width: 450px;
height: 220px;
z-index: 2;
text-align: center;
padding: 20px;
box-sizing: border-box;
 
}

.popup .close-btn {
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
right: 20px;
top: 20px;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
background: #222;
color: #fff;
font-size: 25px;
font-weight: 600;
line-height: 30px;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 50%;
}

.popup.active {
display: block;
}

.popup.active .content {
transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}

.pic::before{
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
font-size: 25px;
font-weight: bold;
width: 100%;
margin-top: -100px;
opacity: 0;
transition: .3s;
transition-delay: .2s;
 }
.pic:after{
content: "";
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
border-radius: 10px;
height: 0;
background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0,.4);
transition: .3s;
}
.pic:hover::after{
height: 100%;
}
.pic:hover::before{
margin-top: 0;
opacity: 1;
}
<div class="photo-gallery">
<div class="pic website">
  <button onclick="togglePopup()"><img 
src="https://i.ibb.co/W5RWrch/Screenshot-2024-12-24-194906.png" 
alt="Button Image"></button>
</div>

<script src="C:\Users\Marks\Desktop\portfolio 
website\pages\projects.js"></script>

<div class="popup" id="popup-1">
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="content">
<div class="close-btn">&times;</div>
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>weeeeeeeewooooooooooo</p>
 </div>
</div>




the code I use allows the js file to be anywhere one the page. The code will execute when the page has loaded. Please see the updated explanation in my answer

When you set the active class on your popup, you do not actually unhide the popup itself. You need to add the below code to your CSS.
.popup.active {
   display: block;
}

The below code snippet should have the functionality you want.


function togglePopup() {
  document.getElementById("popup-1").classList.toggle("active");
}
.photo-gallery {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.pic {
  margin-top: 130px;
  position: relative;
  height: 230px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px lightgray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pic img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.website::before {
  content: "This website!";
  text-align: center;
}

.popup .overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 1;
}

.popup {
  display: none;
}

.popup .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: #fff;
  width: 450px;
  height: 220px;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.popup .close-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #222;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.popup.active {
  display: block;
}

.popup.active .overlay {
  display: block;
}

.popup.active .content {
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}

.pic::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -100px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .3s;
  transition-delay: .2s;
}

.pic:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, .4);
  transition: .3s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.pic:hover::after {
  height: 100%;
}

.pic:hover::before {
  margin-top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Replace src with path to JavaScript starting from your project root (main project file) -->
  <script src="projects.js"></script>

  <!-- Replace href with path to CSS file starting from your proejct root (main project file) -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

  <!-- Your PROJECT ROOT is likely "portfolio website" -->
</head>

<body>
  <div class="photo-gallery">
    <div class="pic website">
      <button onclick="togglePopup()"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/W5RWrch/Screenshot-2024-12-24-194906.png" alt="Button Image"></button>
    </div>

    <div class="popup" id="popup-1">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="content">
        <!-- Added onclick to make the close button function -->
        <div class="close-btn" onclick="togglePopup()">&times;</div>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>weeeeeeeewooooooooooo</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>



Please keep in mind that your code doesn't have anything to close the popup yet, but I'm assuming you were planning on that functionality once you got the general function of the popup fixed. However, I can provide some assistance with that if needed.

I edited the code to be just like this and it's not working when I try it on my web page, that's weird because it works when I press run-code on here.

That's odd. The two solutions I could think of would be making sure you have JavaScript enabled for your website and making sure you have the JavaScript properly linked/loaded in your code. Also, I changed a few things in your code for debugging purposes (missing div tag and translateY values, so make sure those changes have also been made.

is there a way I can send over my entire code for each language & you could maybe see what I'm doing wrong? ty for the feedback btw

That's fine, but the main thing I would (probably) need to see is your implementation of your java script (i.e. script tags ) which you can add to your original question as an edit. I would make a separate code snippet and just include your HTML structure like <head>, <body>, and your relevant script tags. Technically speaking, you could also link a CodePen link here in the comments, but that's typically frowned upon behavior on Stack Overflow.

Using CodePen isn't "wrong," but generally, everything on Stack Overflow should be as self-contained within the site as possible. However, since this is a comment section, I don't think it matters as much. Anyway, looking at the code you provided, I don't think you have any <script> tags to actual link your JavaScript code to the code on your page. Here is a GeeksForGeeks link that explains how to add JavaScript to your code. I would use either the <body> tag or external JavaScript method.

I thought I already did that in my js code? I did the "external" method. I just tried doing it the  way & it doesn't work still

You have the JavaScript code setup right, but in your IDE/text editor (whatever you are using to code that doesn't have built-in HTML, CSS, and JS linking), you need to add a reference to your JavaScript file. You need to add <script src="path/to/javascript/file"></script> right BEFORE your closing </body> tag. Basically, just like with your CSS stylesheet, you have to link to your JavaScript, but the location you do that in the code is slightly different.

Ok I just did it but it's still not working, (checkl my edit)

First, I would start from your root directory for your script, just like you did for styles.css. As for location of the <script> tags, it needs to be in your <head> section or RIGHT BEFORE the </body> tag (there should be nothing between it and the closing body tag).

Ok, thank you for being patient and helping me. So I did what you said, and that still didn't work. I add more code to the CSS (check my post edit) to show more context. I'm thinking the issue is probably with the overlay I had added for when the user hovers over each box. Maybe that's what's preventing it from working and not the actual code itself? I'm thinking it might be blocking the user from clicking on the box for the popup to show up.

No problem. I edited the code in my answer to reflect what your code should look like (with some comments for context in the <head> section. When I did a test server edit of the code, it worked for me with no errors in the JavaScript. If this still does not work for you, I would try testing your website and using Inspect Element (or whatever Dev Tool your browser has), clicking on the button, and seeing what Java Script errors pop up.

wait I'm sorry but I recognized I didn't properly edit my intial post with the added code. Could you re-check? On my end it still doesn't work when I press "run code" on my initial code.

The code you have currently in your initial post has the popup appear when you hover over the image currently. The new code in my answer is pretty much the same but shows ALL the necessary HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code you need. I think the script code in your initial post is not working because the file path is likely wrong, and it's in the wrong space. You don't need to copy and paste everything in my answer exactly, but the structure should be somewhat similar. If you have any questions about the file path, please let me know.

You had a class .overlay on the active class, so the popup was not targetted
.popup.active .overlay {
I advise you to delegate
This code can handle more than one popup and more than one button - it also closes the popup on click on the (X)
Instead of data-tgt you COULD use nextElementSibling but this code allows you to pup the toggle where you want.
It is not really a toggle since you cannot click it to close the popup
I also closed the gallery div and translateY will ignore your second parameter
If you externalise the JavaScript, use relative addressing like
<script src="js/popup.js"></script>


window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const gallery = document.querySelector('.photo-gallery');
  const popups = gallery.querySelectorAll('.popup')
  gallery.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const open = e.target.closest('button.toggle');
    const close = e.target.closest('div.close-btn');
    if (!open && !close) return; // neither open nor close
    let currentPopup;
    if (open) {
      const dataTarget = open.dataset.tgt;
      currentPopup = document.getElementById(dataTarget);
    } else currentPopup = close.closest('div.popup')
    popups.forEach(popup => {
      popup.classList.toggle("active", popup === currentPopup && !close);
    });
  });
});
.photo-gallery {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.pic {
  margin-top: 130px;
  position: relative;
  height: 230px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px lightgray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pic img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.website::before {
  content: "This website!";
  text-align: center;
}

.popup .overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 1;
}

.popup {
  display: none;
}


.popup .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: #fff;
  width: 450px;
  height: 220px;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;

}

.popup .close-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #222;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.popup.active {
  display: block;
}

.popup.active .content {
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}
<div class="photo-gallery">
  <div class="pic website">
    <button class="toggle" data-tgt="popup-1"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/W5RWrch/Screenshot-2024-12-24-194906.png" alt="Button Image"></button>
  </div>

  <div class="popup" id="popup-1">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="close-btn">&times;</div>
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>weeeeeeeewooooooooooo</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




You could use a <dialog>. Details are commented in example.


// Reference <dialog>
const dialog = document.querySelector("dialog");
// Reference <form>
const gallery = document.forms.gallery;
// Reference form controls in <form>
const io = gallery.elements;

/*
 Opens <dialog> as a modal which means 
 everything NOT clickable with the exception
 being the <dialog> of course.
*/
const open = e => {
  dialog.showModal();
};

/*
 #open button will call open() function when
 the user clicks it.
*/
io.open.addEventListener("click", open);
#open {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px 2px 1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px 4px 2px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px 8px 4px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px 16px 8px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px 32px 16px;
}

dialog button {
  float: right;
  margin: 3px 3px 0 0;
  padding-top: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px 2px 1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px 4px 2px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px 8px 4px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px 16px 8px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px 32px 16px;
}

figure {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  width: 80%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

dialog {
  max-width: 60vw;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1.5px solid rgb(128 128 128);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: display 1s allow-discrete, overlay 1s allow-discrete;
  animation: close 1s forwards;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19) 0px 10px 20px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23) 0px 6px 6px;

  &[open] {
    animation: open 1s forwards;
  }
}

@keyframes open {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes close {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
<button id="open" type="button" form="gallery">
  <img 
src="https://i.ibb.co/W5RWrch/Screenshot-2024-12-24-194906.png" 
alt="Button Image">
</button>

<dialog>
  <form id="gallery" method="dialog">
    <figure>
      <figcaption>
        <button>Ｘ</button>
      </figcaption>
      <img
src="https://i.ibb.co/W5RWrch/Screenshot-2024-12-24-194906.png"
alt="Popup Image">
    </figure>
  </form>
</dialog>



